# spaces in ID and putting variable in ID jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to put spaces in id and also i want to select an id using variable.

The id i want to achieve is something like this 
`<span id="printroofG.I. Sheet" class="underline"></span>`

Lets say i have this variable.

`var id = G.I. Sheet`;

and this is my selector

`$('span[id=printroof'+value.material+']').text(value.material);`

> I get unrecognized expression: span[id=printroofG.I. Sheet].

What is the proper way to have spaces in `ID` and use variable as selector.

Comment: The proper way is to **NOT** have spaces in `ID`! Use `data-*` if you wanted to store some data that you'd like to use later on.

Comment: If i will use data-id i will have a condition checking if the span has `data-id = variable` right?is there a one line code for that?with out `if(){}`?

Comment: $('span[data-id="+variable+"]');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said earlier, do not use an `ID` for this purpose. You'd be better of using `data-*` as below.

```
var id = "G.I. Sheet";

$('span[data-id="printroof' + id + '"]').text("Some text");
//OR
$('span[data-id="printroof' + value.material + '"]').text(value.material);
```

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/muzggms6/)

HTML:

```
<span data-id="printroofG.I. Sheet" class="underline"></span>
```

Comment: what is the difference between `var id = 'G.I. Sheet';
$('span[data-id='+id+']').html('&#10004;');` and your answer?

Comment: can you check my fiddle i followed your suggestion i tried making it but i get error what is the difference between our code can you checl

Comment: Missing double quotes: [http://jsfiddle.net/3fwzk7xo/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/3fwzk7xo/2/)

Comment: An `id` is meant to be used as an identifier and not to store arbitrary data, like you've been trying to do.

Comment: i have been thinking of other way but i can think of any thank for suggestion. great help

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to do this use double quotes:

```
$('span[id="printroof'+value.material+'"]').text(value.material);
```

But don't do it.  As lshettyl suggested perhaps it is better to use the jquery [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) api for this.