# How can I add a variable into an ID when creating an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a new div with a new ID on each click of the button. Ex: click once, the div will have ID `"newItem1"` then `"newItem2"` and so on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var itemNumber = 1;

    $("#post").click(function(){
        $("body").append('<div id="newItem + itemNumber"><div>');
        itemNumber++;
    });
});
```

Comment: concat properly like `id="newItem"' + itemNumber+'"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spaces in ID and putting variable in ID jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565178/spaces-in-id-and-putting-variable-in-id-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Variable inside string without concatenation - like PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/javascript-variable-inside-string-without-concatenation-like-php)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the variable like the following:

```
$("body").append('<div id="newItem' + itemNumber.toString() + '"><div>');
```

Or in ECMAScript 6 like the following:

```
$("body").append(`<div id="newItem${itemNumber}"><div>`);
```